# My windows 8.1 can't upgrade to windows 10, the system requirements seem to screw me up hard

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-installation

The title almost states my problem. Take a glimpse of my system as below,
[image: my system]

Windows 10 requires it to have a different CPU core type. I think my computer is dying.

I've tried to run the Media Creation Tool anyway, yet still failed to make it work.
Looking at the error log file, I can see there are many of them in the content. I chop off its tail to show you as follows,

```
2022-09-09 18:51:03, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 18:51:05, Error                 MIG    Ignoring replacement manifest with no settingsVersionRange or versionRange attribute in migration element: Microsoft-Windows-Container-Manager
2022-09-09 18:51:14, Error      [0x080366] MIG    String or RParan expected. Script MigXmlHelper.RelativeMove('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Holographic\DisplayThrottling [Enabled]',
            'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Holographic\DisplayThrottling [ThrottleExperience]')
2022-09-09 18:51:14, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Callback entry point MigXmlHelper.RelativeMove('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Holographic\DisplayThrottling [Enabled]',
            'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Holographic\DisplayThrottling [ThrottleExperience]') not found. __cdecl Mig::CMXEScriptCaller::CMXEScriptCaller(class UnBCL::String *,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2022-09-09 19:12:03, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: CBrgUnattend::CollectBridgeSettings failed: 0x1, 0
2022-09-09 19:44:55, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\SSISTELEMETRY130. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:44:56, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\SQLTELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER2016. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:44:56, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER2016. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:44:56, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSOLAP$MSSQLSERVER2016. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:44:56, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\SSASTELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER2016. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:45:00, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER2016. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:45:00, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MsDtsServer130. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:45:00, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLFDLauncher$MSSQLSERVER2016. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:45:00, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER2016. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:45:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:45:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2022-09-09 19:45:11, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2022-09-09 19:45:44, Error                 SP     CAddCbsPackage::DoExecute: Failed to add package Add [1] package C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\DUImageSandbox\SSU-19041.1852-x64.cab. Error: 0x80004001
2022-09-09 19:45:44, Error                 SP     CAddCbsPackage::DoExecute: Failed to check new OS image health. Error: 0x80004005[gle=0x0000007a]
2022-09-09 19:45:45, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Add [1] package C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\DUImageSandbox\SSU-19041.1852-x64.cab. Error: 0x80004005[gle=0x000000b7]
2022-09-09 19:45:45, Error                 SP     Cannot revert execution of operation 44 (Mount WIM file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\winre.wim, index 1 to C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount). Execution queue is now compromised.
2022-09-09 19:45:45, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Failed execution phase Pre-Finalize. Error: 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:45, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: ExecuteCurrentOperations reported failure!
2022-09-09 19:45:45, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Using action error code: [0x80004005]
2022-09-09 19:45:45, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionPreFinalize::ExecuteRoutine(579): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Execute(493): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteAction(3300): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteActions(3454): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Execute(1631): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2630): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2593): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(944): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:45:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(410): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:46:22, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(295): Result = 0x80004005
2022-09-09 19:46:22, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(433): Result = 0x80004005
```

The story hasn't finished yet. I have looked up ways to enable Secure Boot in my system (Vostro 270s). I know how to do it, I just mean to boot my Windows 8.1 in Secure Boot Mode. But it doesn't work. Some firmware I am unsure seems to prevent the boot loader from doing it jobs. I have been using this computer for 8 years and am a bit sad if I have to see it stuck and gone with only windows 8.1.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you think that _"Windows 10 requires it to have a different CPU core type"_? Why do you think that the computer is dying? What exactly doesn't work with Secure Boot enabled? All of this sounds like three independent questions.

Comment: Windows 8.1 has no different hardware requirements from 10. Yes, enable Secure Boot, and install Windows 10 from USB; you should not need to boot 8.1. If you cannot create a USB flash drive with Media Creation Tool, have a friend do it on another PC. Finally, since even Windows 10 is a dead end, and your PC might not have the ability to run Windows **11**, try a different OS that will continut to be supported, e.g., Ubuntu.

Comment: Your system is more than capable of running Windows 10. As for the reason the upgrade to Windows 10 is failing would require you to provide adequate amount of the logs. Secure Boot isn’t required for Windows 10.

Comment: it could be a bios issue, I have an old HP with 8.1 and cannot be upgraded successfully to W10 due to the bios.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Win10 USB using an earlier version of Windows 10? You might have more luck with 1909.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 will for sure upgrade to Windows 10. I have a Lenovo X230 from 2013 that ran Windows 10 for years and then into Windows 11 Insider. It runs.

Get the Dell Hardware Diagnostics Test App and check all your hardware.

See if the hardware is OK - Sounds like no.

Try updating BIOS from a bootable CD (possibly USB) from the Dell Driver site. Also try updating other drivers if you can.

Your machine indeed may be dying at 8 years of age - not uncommon.

If it fails hardware tests (of any kind), then it is time to replace the machine.